# How do I replace a HTML string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Please guys I want to replace a HTML string using JavaScript but its not working `$("#div_id").HTML($("#div_id").html().replace (/<<(.*?)>>/g, "{{$1}}"));` I know am getting something wrong, any help?

Comment: String is replaces but updated string is not applied... Use `.html(UpdatedStriing)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare updated html in a variable and then apply it as a new html

```
var newHTML = $("#div_id").html().replace (/<<(.*?)>>/g, "{{$1}}");

$("#div_id").html(newHTML);
```